# etrade OAuth HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request with github.com/mrjones/oauth

Tags: go

I am trying to connect to an E-Trade Sandbox, but I keep getting a 400. I tried a few other libraries too and got the same result.
With Post am and able to get a token, so my credentials are correct.

Error

```
    2023/06/25 12:41:27 getBody: httpExecute: HTTP response is not 200/OK as expected. Actual response: 
            Response Status: '400 400'
            Response Code: 400
            Response Body: <!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request</title><style type="text/css">h1 

...


 The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).</p><hr class="line" /><h3></h3></body></html>
            Request Headers: [key: Authorization, val: OAuth oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fcallback",oauth_consumer_key="fb...1d2884",oauth_nonce="8576997036700485716",oauth_signature="91oNjhRVVD...Ctz0SH88%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1687689686",oauth_version="1.0"]
```

---

### code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/mrjones/oauth"
)

const (
    consumerKey    = "fb746...1d2884"
    consumerSecret = "1c1c1...78c8a8f992a9"
    callbackURL    = "http://localhost:8081/callback"
)

var (
    sessionStore *sessions.CookieStore
    oauthClient  *oauth.Consumer
)

func main() {
    sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("your_session_key"))

    oauthClient = oauth.NewConsumer(
        consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
        oauth.ServiceProvider{
        RequestTokenUrl:   "https://apisb.etrade.com/oauth/request_token",
        AuthorizeTokenUrl: "https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize",
        AccessTokenUrl:    "https://etws.etrade.com/oauth/access_token",
        },
    )

    http.HandleFunc("/login", handleLogin)
    http.HandleFunc("/callback", handleCallback)
    http.HandleFunc("/reauthenticate", handleReauthenticate)

    log.Println("Server started at http://localhost:8081")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}

func handleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    requestToken, requestURL, err := oauthClient.GetRequestTokenAndUrl(callbackURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        http.Error(w, "Failed to get request token", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "session-name")
    session.Values["request_token"] = requestToken
    session.Save(r, w)

    http.Redirect(w, r, requestURL, http.StatusFound)
}

func handleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "session-name")
    requestToken := session.Values["request_token"].(*oauth.RequestToken)

    accessToken, err := oauthClient.AuthorizeToken(requestToken, r.FormValue("oauth_verifier"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to authorize token", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    session.Values["access_token"] = accessToken
    session.Save(r, w)

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Authorization successful!")
}
```

Has anyone has similar issues when trying to connect to e-trades sandbox platform?